# Executing query in afterTransactionBegin method of Hibernate interceptor

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, transactions, interceptor

I've added a `Hibernate Interceptor` and overridden `afterTransactionBegin` method and I'm trying to execute a database query in this method.

```
 public void afterTransactionBegin(Transaction tx) {
    LOG.info("Transaction begin: {}", applicationContext.getBean(ITxnDao.class).getCurrentTransactionId().toString());
}
```

But I'm getting

```
Caused by: org.hibernate.HibernateException: No Session found for current thread
 at org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.SpringSessionContext.currentSession(SpringSessionContext.java:106)
 at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.getCurrentSession(SessionFactoryImpl.java:1039)
```

which means `transaction` has not actually begun yet. Is there some way I can achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

The transaction is already started when the `afterTransactionBegin` Interceptor method is called. In your case, you have a Spring related issue.

Make sure you call the DAO logic from a Service method that's annotated with `@Transactional`.